# Error triggered when reading structured values

Tags: c++, istream

I'm trying to figure out why this code from "Programming Principle and Practice using C++" triggers the error ("bad reading"):

```
#include "D:\std_lib_facilities.h"
/*
 get it from: https://github.com/ltr01/Programming- 
 _Principles_and_Practice_Using_Cpp/blob/master/std_lib_facilities.h
*/
struct Reading
{
    int day;
    int hour;
    double temperature;
};
istream &operator>>(istream &is, Reading &r)
// format: ( 3 4 9.7 )
{
    char ch1;
    if (is >> ch1 && ch1 != '(') // first try the format (day, hour, temperature)
    {                            // could it be a Reading?
        is.unget();              // puts the character back so we can read it in some other way
        is.clear(ios_base::failbit); // puts the istream in fail() state
        return is;                   // return allows us to try to read in some other way
    }
    char ch2;
    int d;
    int h;
    double t;
    is  >> d >> h >> t >> ch2;
    if (!is || ch2 != ')')    // the istream it's not good
        error("bad reading"); // messed-up reading = we bail out because the format is wrong
    return is;
    r.day = d;    
    r.hour = h; 
    r.temperature = t;
    return is; // 
}
void fill_from_file(vector<Reading> &v, const string &name) 
{
    ifstream ist{name}; // open file for reading
    if (!ist)
        error("can't open input file ", name); // 
    // . . . use ist . . .
    for (Reading r; ist >> r;) 
        v.push_back(r);
}

int main()
try
{
    vector<Reading> day1; // a day is a vector of readings
    fill_from_file(day1, "10.5_reading_in.txt");
    for (Reading r : day1)
        cout << r.day << ' ' << r.hour << ' ' << r.temperature << '\n';
}

catch (exception &e) 
{
    cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << endl;
    return 1;
}
catch (...)
{
    cerr << "Unknown exception!\n";
    return 2;
}
```

When I'm trying to read this file:

```
(1 1 1.1)
(2 2 2.2)
(3 3 3.3)
(4 4 4.4)
(5 5 5.5)
(6 6 6.6)
(7 7 7.7)
(8 8 8.8)
(9 9 9.9)
```

My understanding of what's going on is this:

1. we read the first character and if it's not a "(" it puts the character back in the istream (with unget), set's the state to fail and returns the istream to try to read it in some other way
2. now it tries to read it without the parenthesis (that's the code from the book) but because the first character really is a "(" I get the "bad reading" error
3. I tried to change the code by reading also ch1, like below, but the error("bad reading") is triggered again:

   is  >> ch1 >> d >> h >> t >> ch2;

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot for your answers!

Update: Thank you Manuel for your reply but I wasn't able to make it work with your modifications. Instead it seems to work if I exit the function when I reach "End of File". If I don't put "return is" there, then somehow the condition (ch2 != ')') is always true and I get the error "bad reading" :

```
// test for end of file or istream error
if (!is) // meaning when is=0 - when it reaches the end
    {
        if (is.eof())
            cout << "Finished" << '\n';
            return is;
        if (is.fail())
            error("wrong character type"); 
    }
    // test for wrong file format
if (ch2 != ')')
    {
        cout << "Readed: " << ch2 << '\n';
        error("bad reading");
    }
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] so we can run this code and see what problem is.

Comment: also there is missing braces and as a result you have a dead code. So I'm suspecting typo error.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/eBbIhV9bJNUnLs6f

Comment: I edited to show the whole program. Thanks!

Comment: @Theodore That's not the whole program. It's missing headers, a function and at least one `using` directive. Check: https://godbolt.org/z/dfsMGc

Comment: true, I'm also including the "std_lib_facilities.h" from [here](https://github.com/ltr01/Programming-_Principles_and_Practice_Using_Cpp/blob/master/std_lib_facilities.h)

Comment: I've test it, reproduce issue and it is a typo (missing braces). There are other minor issues, basicly it works when typo is fixed: https://godbolt.org/z/f48Y4r

Comment: @Theodore When creating a [mcve], include the code you use in the question. Don't link to external sites. The header file you linked to contains a lot of irrelevant stuff and a huge amount of headers that aren't needed for this.

Comment: @Theodore I've corrected my response. You have to handle somehow the end of file, that's why I didn't put the return I don't know how you want to handle that, but yes, without the return it just goes to the following statement.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you Marek for your reply. It works, just like you said, with braces. The confusing part now is that Bjarne Stroustrup's code from the book doesn't have that "return is" after error("bad reading"). I don't know why I added it in my first post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put two conditions to check for input stream and character read you will see the error:

```
    if (!is) {
        cout << "Finished" << endl;
        return is;
    }
    
    if (ch2 != ')') {   // the istream it's not good
        cout << "Readed: " << ch2 << endl;
        error("bad reading"); // messed-up reading = we bail out because the format is wrong
    }
```

Ouput:

```
Finished
Readed: 
bad reading
```

You file is finished. All is read correctly but the file ends.

And you have an extra return:

```
    if (!is || ch2 != ')')
        error("bad reading");

    return is;  // <-- I suppose this was for debugging, remove it
    r.day = d;    
    r.hour = h; 
    r.temperature = t;
    return is; //
```

With those changes my output is:

```
Finished
Readed: 
bad reading
1 1 1.1
2 2 2.2
3 3 3.3
4 4 4.4
5 5 5.5
6 6 6.6
7 7 7.7
8 8 8.8
9 9 9.9
```

In your last edited code:

```
if (is.eof())
     cout << "Finished" << '\n';
     return is;
```

should have curly braces:

```
if (is.eof()) {
     cout << "Finished" << '\n';
     return is;
}
```

Indentation in C++ doesn't mean anything.

Comment: this is what I commented 40 minutes ago.

Comment: @MarekR I didn't see your comment until I published the response. In any case, OP has a test for two different things (end of file or istream error and wrong file format) and I don't think that's a typo because both things should be treated differently.